# Weird scaling constraint on 3d model in edit mode

Tags: 3d-manipulator

so im in edit mode with my model however when I select a face and try to scale it it scales the model not just the face please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that proportional editing is turned off or disabled
[image]

Comment: ty this fixed the problem